# Dynamic jump to a tab and change its content at the same time?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabhost

In the first tab I have a listview from where I extract a string, and in the second tab I have a textview. When i click an item in the list, I should go in the second tab and and the string value should be displayed in the textview.

```
public static String mystring;
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    mystring = listofHashMap.get(position).get("keyname").toString(); //it's ok here
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code above(placed in ListViewActivity) is what i have tried and it works (but *MyActivity* is not anymore a tabcontent,it is a full-screen standalone activity), having the following code snippet in MyActivity:

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvid);
lv = new ListViewActivity();
tv.setText(lv.mystring);
```

But, as I said I want that *MyActivity* to be a tabcontent,so I have tried this:

```
 public MyTabActivity taba = new MyTabActivity();
 protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    mystring = listofHashMap.get(position).get("keyname").toString();
    int i=1;//the tab where I want to go, and MyActivity is its content 
    taba.ChangeTab(i);
}
```

*ChangeTab()* is a **static** method within *MyTabActivity*(the activity that extends TabActivity ) which simply does **setCurrentTab(i)** .

So, doing this, *MyActivity* will always display the name of first clicked item, even I select other items in the list then.I belive that what i have to do is **setContent()** again for *MyActivity* or do something with that **static String mystring**, I have tried many solutions but with no result. I tried to be as accurate I could on what i want to do, please some help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a broadcast. I think that the timing would require a sticky broadcast. Maybe something like this:

```
public MyTabActivity taba = new MyTabActivity();
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    mystring = listofHashMap.get(position).get("keyname").toString();

    // create the intent to send and give it the data
    Intent i = new Intent("updateTextView");
    i.putExtra("textFromList", mystring);
    sendStickyBroadcast(i);

    int i=1;//the tab where I want to go, and MyActivity is its content 
    taba.ChangeTab(i);
}
```

And then in MyActivity, write something like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // your onCreate method
    registerReceiver(updateTextReceiver, new IntentFilter("updateTextView"));
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // your onDestroy method
    unregisterReceiver(updateTextReceiver);
}

private BroadcastReceiver updateTextReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvid);
        String myString = intent.getStringExtra("textFromList");
        if (myString != null) {
            tv.setText(myString);
        }
    }

};
```

For the sticky broadcast, there's an additional permission needed in the manifest. I'm not sure but maybe you could just send a regular broadcast if you swapped the order of sending the broadcast and changing the tab.

Comment: EXCELLENT! I'm impressed :) The permission needed is: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/> .It is a very simple and elegant solution. PS: I was trying to solve it with TabContentFactory() and createTabContent() and I'm interested to know, as a solution in the future, if  could it be done in this way, what do you say?

Comment: I was not aware of that solution. I'm not sure it would work for you because that method returns a View, and it's my understanding that you want to have `MyActivity` launch.